# Importing py from sibling directory gives Attempted relative import in non-package error

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I've been searching on stackoverflow and can't find out what's wrong.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
--project
  --__init__.py
  --helpers
    --__init__.py
    --functions.py
  --set1
    --__init__.py
    --foo.py
  --set2
    --__init__.py
  --setn
    --__init__.py
```

In `foo.py` I want to import `functions.py`
I do this with

```
from ..helpers import functions
```

And this is giving me the error:

```
Attempted relative import in non-package error
```

All of the answers I've found so far deal with setting up **init**.py properly.

Using python2.7 on Mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `from project.helpers import functions`, you're not actually using your script as a package. See her for more info: [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)